# Traverse and Import into GridFS/MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, input, gridfs

I am looking to integrate two programs that I have written. The first is an I/O stream that traverses through a directory and lists all of the files within each folder. The second uses the Java driver for MongoDB and allows the input of a file (in this case an image). I want to combine the two so that when the directory is traversed, the files are uploaded as it comes across them. Any help is appreciated. Here are my two sources of code:

Stream:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryIteratorException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class StreamTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamTest streamTest = new StreamTest();
    Path readyPath = Paths.get("Ready");
    try {
        List<Path> sourceList = streamTest.listSourceFiles(readyPath);
        for (Path p : sourceList) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(p)) {
                streamTest.processFolder(p);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sourceList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void processFolder(Path p) throws IOException {
    List<Path> sourceList = listSourceFiles(p);
    Collections.sort(sourceList, new Comparator<Path>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Path path1, Path path2) {
            if (path1.endsWith(".csv")) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("ID = " + Math.random());
    System.out.println(sourceList);
}
List<Path> listSourceFiles(Path dir) throws IOException {
    List<Path> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*")) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            result.add(entry);
        }
    } catch (DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
        throw ex.getCause();
    }
    return result;
  }
 }
```

Input:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile;

public class ImageDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost", 27017)).getDB("JMP");
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;

    GridFS images = new GridFS(db, "images"); //Returns GidFS bucket named "images"
    try{
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("banner3.png");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't open file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    GridFSInputFile image = images.createFile(inputStream, "banner3.png");

    //create some meta data for the object
    BasicDBObject meta = new BasicDBObject("description", "images and csv's");
    image.setMetaData(meta);
    image.save();

    System.out.println("Object ID in Files Collection: " + image.get("_id"));
    System.out.println("Saved the file to MongoDB");
    System.out.println("Now let's read it back out");

    GridFSDBFile gridFile = images.findOne(new BasicDBObject("filename", "banner3.png"));

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("banner3_copy.png");
    gridFile.writeTo(outputStream);

    System.out.println("write the file back out");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect this to the "image driver" which is where the connections and inserts into Mongo are...

```
    private void processImages(List<Path> sourceList) throws IOException { 
    //create same method but for CSV without using GridFS
    for (Path file : sourceList) {
        if (file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".png")) {

    System.out.println(ImageDriver.uploadImage(file.toAbsolutePath()));
```